# How do I make a method or event run on the first startup of a C# Program?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I was wondering if its possible to call an event or method the first time a program starts up, and obviously on the first time. Is this possible to do in C#? If so could someone show some examples of how this is accomplished

Comment: Do you mean on the first time it runs on the computer, but not subsequent executions?

Comment: So... basically a 'one-time only' run? or.. it can run only once after every (re)boot of the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240.aspx) native method by specifying the `DelayUntilReboot` flag on some lock file:

```
class Program
{
    [Flags]
    enum MoveFileFlags
    {
        None = 0,
        ReplaceExisting = 1,
        CopyAllowed = 2,
        DelayUntilReboot = 4,
        WriteThrough = 8,
        CreateHardlink = 16,
        FailIfNotTrackable = 32,
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern bool MoveFileEx(
        string lpExistingFileName,
        string lpNewFileName,
        MoveFileFlags dwFlags
    );

    static void Main()
    {
        string lockFile = "foo.dat";
        if (!File.Exists(lockFile))
        {
            // that's a first run after the reboot => create the file
            File.WriteAllText(lockFile, "");

            // Mark the file for deletion after reboot
            MoveFileEx(lockFile, null, MoveFileFlags.DelayUntilReboot);

            Console.WriteLine("it's a first run");
        }
        else
        {
            // that's a consecutive run
            Console.WriteLine("it's a consecutive run");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this works OK for console apps, although how could I use this within a Windows Forms app?

Comment: @Dennis, well, in a WinForms application you still have a Program.cs launcher and a `Main` method, don't you? So simply put this code there before creating the main form. Or you could also put it in the constructor of the main form but that would be waste because if the application shouldn't run you probably don't need to wait so much in order to terminate it.

Comment: Ahh I see, well I have managed to get it working in a GUI app (nearly!), although I get this error: The name 'MoveFileEx' does not exist in the current context. Which namespace am I missing?

Comment: @Dennis, where did you declare this method? Make it public and then use the class it is declared in to access it: `SomeClass.MoveFileEx`.

Comment: Well after argiung with VS for a while I finaly managed to get it working! :) Replaced the ConsoleLines with ShowMessageBox and all was good! You'll have to excuse my pace, I've only been learning to program the last 24 hours lol. It's no wonder your one of the top members here, I genuinely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a file to disk or a value to the registry when the program is run the first time.

You check the existence of whatever you set - if it doesn't exist, you run your method, if it does, you don't.

Comment: @Dennis - It is not something needed by all programs and is easy to achieve. Why put it into the framework (where it will need to be written, tested, documented etc for relatively little benefit).

Comment: but if you reboot the file will still be there isn't it?

Comment: @Darin - it will be, but the question isn't clear. I can't tell if the requirement is to run the method on the first time it reboots or just the first time it runs, regardless of reboots. I have assumed the second, you have assumed the first.